# Correct Firebase auth configuration for Vue.js app

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to set up firebase auth using the firebaseui module in a vue.js app. I'm not completely sure how to set up the firebase imports and implement firebaseui in the vue.js environment.
I've created a separate firebaseInit.js in the src folder:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app"
import { getFunctions, connectFunctionsEmulator } from "firebase/functions";
import { getFirestore, collection } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "..."
};

// Initialize Firebase
export const firebaseApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore();
// here we can export reusable database references
export const todosRef = collection(db, 'todos')

const functions = getFunctions();
connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, "127.0.0.1", 5001);

// Initialize Firebase Authentication and get a reference to the service
export const firebaseAuth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
```

Then in main.js:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import './index.css'
import './firebaseInit'

const app = createApp(App)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app')
```

And finally in the script portion of the view.vue:

```
import { getFirestore, collection, addDoc, doc, getDoc, getDocs, query, where } from "firebase/firestore";
import * as firebaseui from 'firebaseui'
import 'firebaseui/dist/firebaseui.css';
import { firebaseAuth } from '@/firebaseInit';
import { firebaseApp } from '@/firebaseInit';

// Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebaseAuth);

ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
  signInOptions: [
    firebaseApp.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
  ],
  // Other config options...
});
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'EmailAuthProvider')

The Firebase documentation actually has the following code for implementing the UI (https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui):

```
var firebase = require('firebase');
var firebaseui = require('firebaseui');

// Initialize the FirebaseUI Widget using Firebase.
var ui = new firebaseui.auth.AuthUI(firebase.auth());
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
  signInOptions: [
    firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID
  ],
  // Other config options...
});
```

But since I'm using the vite bundler I'm not importing 'firebase' with the require function.